# Redirect Eclipse Tomcat logs to Console (without ConcoleAppender)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging, log4j

I'm using Eclipse with an external Tomcat ("use tomcat installation, takes control of tomcat").

Our application logs are currently configured with `log4j` using a `FileAppender`.

Is it possible to redirect the log messages to the eclipse console **without** using a `ConsoleAppender`?

I tried it with a `ConsoleAppender` and it works fine, but then I have to create an extra `log4j.properties` file for development and production mode (as we don't want console logs on stage or production systems).

Comment: Two properties files plus consoleappender is the way to go. Otherwise write a custom appender.

Answer (score 2):

**One way is to write your custom appender using code itself and attache that appender to root logger.**

// if it is not production then only execute this mode

```
  ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
  //configure the appender
  String PATTERN = "%d [%p|%c|%C{1}] %m%n";
  console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN)); 
  console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
  console.activateOptions();
  //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
  Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);
```

I don't know your application code but you can patch this code somewhere in your code and logically fix this problem. 
P.S. Again this is just a logical solution. Other way is already known to you that is log4j property file.